# DNS Records cannot read in PowerDNS

Tags: nameserver, dns-zone, powerdns

I have installed the PowerDNS as DNS Server (per this question: [Read DNS Zones from database](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014154/read-dns-zones-from-database/1014158#1014158))

Everything works fine and I can get the response from the DNS server, but no records return from the server. I have two A records but when I run `dig` or `nslookup` no records returned.

For a test, I checked the domain in mxtoolbox.com and I receive a response from the DNS server, but when I stop the `pdns` service or remove the domain from `domains` table, I didn't receive any response. so I'm sure the PowerDNS installed and activated successfully.

When `pdns` is stopped:
[image]

When `pdns` is running:
[image]

Just I don't know why DNS server does not return the DNS records.

Comment: How are you using the `dig` and the `nslookup`? It might be that you are not using these tools correctly. it would help to know the domain/hostname and the IP address of the DNS server(s) in question.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I use this command `dig +trace domain.com`, and I use `+trace` to get more details. for more security, I think it's better to don't provide the IP and Domain here if you want I can send you in a private message

Answer (score 0):

After several trial and error I found that I have to set `gmysql-dnssec` to `no`.
When I set it to `no` my problem has been solved.

```
gmysql-dnssec=no
```